# Migration Challenges: Updating Gnosis Safe Infrastructure becouse gnosis safe has removed older docker images

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I've set up the entire infrastructure for Gnosis Safe on a new EVM chain that initially lacked Gnosis Safe support. However, Gnosis has deprecated that version and removed the corresponding Docker image. As a result, I'm unable to use my Safe wallet. When attempting to set up the new version, it fails to execute transactions, and I suspect it's not accessing the old data and contract addresses. Can someone guide me on how to migrate my data? Additionally, I need assistance in identifying the specific locations within the infrastructure services where I should integrate the older factory and Safe contract to ensure they interact with the smart contracts on the chain correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the safe infra were you using? And what services specifically? You can find older versions of the client gateway here: https://github.com/5afe/safe-client-gateway. You can checkout the old tag and run `docker build` on the required tag:

```
git clone https://github.com/5afe/safe-client-gateway
cd safe-client-gateway
git checkout rust-image-3.15.2 v3.15.2
docker build .
```

Please let me know if you need to use other services. Best, Louis